# Mod_Rewrite Reverse Url Structure

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I wonder is it possible to learn the url structure which is written with mode_rewrite. For example, the url that I have is http://somesite.com/topic-header and there must be a kind of somesite.com?id=123 or somesite.com?title=topic-header. Is there any way to detect that?

Answer (score 0):

Only if you have access to the folder in which the .htaccess file resides (or in the apache configuration files, albeit less used).

It's also common knowledge to redirect any links that are not found on the filesystem to index.php, wordpress does this for example.